# ¿Cómo y dónde modificar la plantilla de toString en NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class ToSt {

    private String nombre;
    private String telefono;
    private  int edad;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ToSt{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", edad=" + edad + '}';
    }
```

Me gustaría modificar la plantilla del método generado por defecto `toString` en NetBeans, pero no encuentro dónde o cómo hacerlo. Si alguien fuera tan amable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Options - Editor, debería ser posible seleccionar el lenguaje y la plantilla a editar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]